# Libre Office Writer - Is Creating a "Text from file" object (MS Word concept) possible with it?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

In MS word I can create a file with a certain text, and than import it to 10 other files in a smart way (if I change the original text, it changes in all the 10 files as well). This is done in Word 2016 from Object > Text from file.

Can this be done in Libre office Writer? - I took a look at the Objects there but didn't find "Text from file" - Maybe another name?

Ben,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with LO Writer, too:

1. Create the file (boilerplate / "text block") that should be inserted in the other documents. You can use any LO file type, e.g. odt (LO Writer).
2. In the file where the text block should apppear, put the cursor where the file should get inserted;
3. Select Menu `Insert` -> `Object` -> `OLE Object`;
4. In the dialog box, select "`create from file`", tick "`Link to file`", and select the "text block" file using the "search..." button:

   [image]